# change column value and textcolor while loading silverlight telerik radgrid

Tags: silverlight, telerik-grid

Can anyone help me in changing foreground color & text of a **silverlight telerik gridview** cell from codebehind.

My actual requirement is,

I have a dataset which contains data.Few columns have data with prefix "r_". Now I need to show this data in grid. And the columns which has prefix "r_" should be displayed in red color. and I should also remove that prefix before showing it in grid.

Ex: MyDataSet

```
Column1          Column2         Column3
Test1            Test2           Test3
Test4            r_Test5         Test6
r_Test7          Test8           r_Test9
```

In the above example r_Test5,r_Test7 & r_Test9 should be displayed as Test5,Test7 & Test9 respectively, but in red color.

Answer (score 1):

Never Mind. found a solution for this.

```
private void dgBank_CellLoaded(object sender, Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.CellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cell is GridViewCell && ((e.Cell.Column).Header== "Column_1") || ((e.Cell.Column).Header== "Column_2") || ((e.Cell.Column).Header== "Column_3"))
        {
            TextBlock txt = e.Cell.Content as TextBlock;
            txt.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0));

            if (txt.Text.StartsWith("r_"))
            {
                var cell = e.Cell;
                txt.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(120, 255, 0, 0));
                txt.Text = txt.Text.Replace("r_", string.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks.